# Log prints different outputs

Tags: go, logrus

I'm having problems with the output of my log messages. I'm using logrus.

I'm developing with VS Code and when I debug my code the log output is:

```
time="2021-05-04T11:52:11+01:00" level=info msg=message
```

But when I'm running the app executable or use **go run main.go** the output is:

```
INFO[0007] message
```

I want the first output.

What is happening?

EDIT:

We need to set the formatter as stated in the [logrus github](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus).

Comment: have you tried 
`To ensure this behaviour even if a TTY is attached, set your formatter as follows:
log.SetFormatter(&log.TextFormatter{DisableColors: true, FullTimestamp: true})`
from: https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus

Comment: I missed that. Yep that works. Thanks @DianBakti

Comment: Please create an answer for your own question and mark it so that other people know that this problem has been fixed and what the solution is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set the formatter as stated in the [logrus github](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus)